# encode url swift withAllowedCharacters not working encoding %20 as %2520 (means encoding % as %25)

Tags: ios, swift, encode, urlencode, encoder

Following is my code for URL encoding

```
extension String {
var encoded: String {
    return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
  }
}
```

But I am facing issue if url contains %20. it is encoding it as %2520 although I have added **urlQueryAllowed**

Original url: https://mydomain.in/retailers_data_v2/retailer/320/17372-Tea%20Coffee%20Vending%20Machine.JPG

Encoded url: https://mydomain.in/retailers_data_v2/retailer/320/17372-Tea%2520Coffee%2520Vending%2520Machine.JPG

Comment: Space is encoded as %20 in the original URL and % is encoded to as %25 in encoded URL. Issue related to double encoding

Comment: no url already contains %20. and it is encoding % as %25

Answer (score 3):

If you have an already encoded URL String, you first need to remove percent encoding before applying it again.

If you aren't sure whether the URL you have is already encoded or not, you can simply use an `if let` on `removingPercentEncoding` and depending on its result, either call `addingPercentEncoding` on the original URL or on the one that you removed the encoding from.

```
let alreadyEncodedURLString = "https://mydomain.in/retailers_data_v2/retailer/320/17372-Tea%20Coffee%20Vending%20Machine.JPG"
if let unencodedURLString = alreadyEncodedURLString.removingPercentEncoding {
    unencodedURLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
} else {
    alreadyEncodedURLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
}
```